# Security access in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony

I'm developing an application in Symfony2. There are two clients:

- Access from intern (employees), enterprise network --> it musts pass by CAS server --> I can use CASBundle to handle it.
- Access from enterprise's visitor, wifi network (for example), he has no id/pwd.

How can I tell my application that visitors connect or employees connect? 
Could you propose a solution for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: which CAS bundle do you want to use?

Comment: I used gorgeCasbundle.